# Angular Event Emit Issues

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-event-emitter

Recently I started a project for a friend and I need to use events. I've only used them once before (just a heads up). Unfortunately I can't seem to get the parent to catch the emit. Here's some code:
The child that emits:

```
 @Output() reset: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 changeRoute(val)
 {
    if (val.url = '/' && this.tuneholder.getTune() != null)
    {
         if (this.tuneholder.getTune().type == this.tune.type){
         this.SetTune(this.tuneholder.getTune())
         this.tuneholder.clearTune();
         console.log("Emit");
         console.log(this.tune);
         this.reset.emit(this.tune);
    }
 }
```

Here's the parent html:

```
<app-playeritem 
[tune]="tune" 
*ngFor="let tune of tunes"
(reset)='resetTuneVal($event)'>
</app-playeritem>
```

Here's the parent typesecript:

```
  resetTuneVal(tune:Tune){
    console.log("Caught Emit");
    console.log(tune);
    this.tunes.forEach(elm => {
       if (elm.type == tune.type){
          this.SetTune(elm, tune);
       }
    });
  }
```

The logs for the emit are present but the logs for catching are not. Any ideas? I feel like I'm doing it alright but I really am lost.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue, as a stackblitz preferrably.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the console (F12 dev tools if you're using Chrome, for example)?

Comment: As in upload all the code, not just the relevant code?

Comment: I see no errors, just the two logs from the child.

Comment: @EuanHollidge not all of your code. It's best to share enough code that we can run and reproduce the issue, such as with StackBlitz.com.

Comment: When I upload the code to StackBlitz.com it works fine, I guess that means something is off with my environment?

Comment: It turns out it is being cause by a router event I'm subscribed to. When I call the function outside of the router event it works fine. Can you emit events inside of other events or does that not work on Angular?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out my issue. I was calling the emit inside the router event. This meant that the parent wasn't what I thought it was, it was actually the parent of the router. I fixed it by running the check on `ngOnInit()` instead as it gets automatically called whenever the elem gets loaded anyways.